# How to send keys combinations to the page using webdriverjs?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, webdriverjs

I was trying to do

```
driver.keyDown(webdriver.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.SPACE);
```

But it says that the method keyDown does not exist!
Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a place where i can see webdriverjs api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to pass CTRL+SPACE to sendkeys you can use Key.chord. 
Try this

```
driver.sendKeys(webdriver.Key.chord(webdriver.Key.CONTROL, webdriver.Key.SPACE))
```

You can find the webdriver js api documentation here http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/